# Logger handler wont work in different classes java

Tags: java, logging, handler

I'm pretty new in Java but I have to write a simple logger.
My problem is that my logger won't transfer its handler.

My first class is:

```
public class LoggerClass {
    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("myLogger");

    FileHandler fh;  
        public LoggerClass() {
        try {
            this.fh = new FileHandler("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Logging%u.txt");
        } catch (IOException | SecurityException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LoggerClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        logger.addHandler(fh);
        SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();  
        fh.setFormatter(formatter); 

    }

}
```

and i want to transfer the logger to another class by doing this:

```
package Logger;
import static Logger.LoggerClass.logger;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;

public class LoggingTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try
    {
      ((Object) null).toString();
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
      logger.log( Level.SEVERE, "oh oh", e );
    }

    logger.info( "Hat funktioniert" );
  }
    }
```

i tried nearly everything that i've found, and the logger functions but it only gives its output on console and not how it should be in a file

Comment: note that you have several things wrong - sharing a logger instance between classes and calling your class interface when it is not for example. Loggers should in general be configured using external configuration, typically static configuration files: .xml or .properties.

Comment: I'm sorry for the "LoggerInterface" thing, it was from a previous try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your test you never configured your logger.  Try this:

```
    package Logger;
    import static Logger.LoggerClass.logger;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.logging.Level;

    //There are better ways to do this.
    static {
       new LoggerClass();
    }

    public class LoggingTest {



    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try
    {
      ((Object) null).toString();
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
      logger.log( Level.SEVERE, "oh oh", e );
    }

    logger.info( "Hat funktioniert" );
  }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("myLogger");
```

To

```
public static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("myLogger");
```

Reason you have given it a default access in your class where you defined Logger and using defail access you can access it in package only. While where you are using is you have another package and hence error.

Apart form above use logger like:

```
LoggerInterface.logger.info( "Hat funktioniert" );
```

Since you defined it static so use classname.instance.method(parameter)